# Ruby: searching for string with partial dynamic contents (Interpolated REGEX??)

Tags: regex, ruby, string, string-interpolation

How in ruby is it possible to search text for a string that can have varying contents e.g.

```
text.include?("match here[generic//regex]and here").should == true
```

the goal is for the regex to match something to the effect of a version number, but we don't necessarily care what the version number is since the rest of the string matches.

Comment: Can you add some examples of what the regex should match and what it shouldn't?

Comment: Is this for RSpec? You may want to add the [tag:rspec] tag.

Comment: input = "ruby version 1.8.7" match on = "ruby version [some numbers]".
how would I match the text and acknowledge that the version exists but not a particular one.  this would be in a step definition inside cucumber tests.

Comment: The wording of the question (e.g. "partial dynamic contents", "variable contents", "interpolated", etc.) does not match at all with the description of the problem. Wouldn't a simple regex with `\d+` do the trick?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make sure there is a version number, and don't mind matching it, you can use:

```
ruby version *\d\.\d(?:\.\d)?
```

If you don't want to match the version number at all, you need a lookahead:

```
ruby version(?= *\d\.\d(?:\.\d)?)
```

matches `ruby version` but checks that we are followed by spaces and a number of the form x.x or x.x.x

**Explain Regex**

```
ruby version             # 'ruby version'
(?=                      # look ahead to see if there is:
   *                     #   ' ' (0 or more times (matching the most
                         #   amount possible))
  \d                     #   digits (0-9)
  \.                     #   '.'
  \d                     #   digits (0-9)
  (?:                    #   group, but do not capture (optional
                         #   (matching the most amount possible)):
    \.                   #     '.'
    \d                   #     digits (0-9)
  )?                     #   end of grouping
)                        # end of look-ahead
```

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Comment: Why do you think this needs lookahead? A plain regex will do what you want, and using lookahead will make it tricky to match _after_ the number.

Comment: @matt When I read it, I thought he didn't want to match the version number at all. Re-reading it now, I see that he doesn't mind matching it as well, so you're right, there is no need for a lookahead. Thanks for the heads up. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd go about it:

```
"ruby version"[/^ruby version [\d.]+/] # => nil
"ruby version 1.8.7"[/^ruby version [\d.]+/] # => "ruby version 1.8.7"
```

Now, this won't work if your version string has any alpha, beta, or similar tags:

```
"ruby version 1.8.7a"[/^ruby version [\d.]+/] # => "ruby version 1.8.7"
```

Notice that it dropped the alpha indicator. If that is significant to you, then add them to the character-set:

```
"ruby version 1.8.7a"[/^ruby version [\d.ab]+/] # => "ruby version 1.8.7a"
```

It's difficult to say for sure what you'll have to capture, since version number formats can vary wildly.